# PlusShare builder setContentUrl() overrides setText()

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to share a Google Play game with the PlusShare.Builder as explained in the doc but the setText has no effect :

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setText(getString(R.string.share))
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.pixelprose.dice"))
                .getIntent();
```

Only the link is displayed with the Google Play icon but the setText has no effect, nothing is displayed. I tried to put a constant String setText("My sample text") but it doesn't worked neither... Is there a limitation with the Google Play links ?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently an issue with google-plus-platform:

[Issue: Code Google.com](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=738)

Use `.setText(message)` alone or `.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link))` alone.

Using `.setContentUrl(uri)` will override text.

Answer (score 0):

I have this ptoblem too. I try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

And this post text. But don't know how i can posting link

**UPDATE**:

PlusShare can't send text and link (url) together.

```
PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(mMainActivity, mPlusClient);
builder.setType("text/plain");
builder.setText(message);
```

If i use this code, i can share text. But if i use this:

```
 builder.setText(message).setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link));
```

i share only link. Why?!

Comment: In there own examples they use both fields - however the API is a bit different: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/prefill